# Microsoft Graph: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application

Tags: javascript, azure, cors, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to Redeem the code for access tokens following the Document [Authorization and sign-in for OneDrive in Microsoft Graph](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online)

This is API that I use for this step

*POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token*

I have already tested the API on Postman and it works fine.

Test Redeem Code on Postman [image]

But when I tried on my code JavaScript, I got an error "Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application" ,

```
{
   "error":"invalid_request",
   "error_description":"AADSTS90023: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type.\r\nTrace ID: 57ebcf82-278c-4375-a4db-b81ab567fc00\r\nCorrelation ID: 5a80b3fa-1e0d-4265-8fbe-5e22df198bee\r\nTimestamp: 2021-04-26 10:26:36Z",
   "error_codes":[
      90023
   ],
   "timestamp":"2021-04-26 10:26:36Z",
   "trace_id":"57ebcf82-278c-4375-a4db-b81ab567fc00",
   "correlation_id":"5a80b3fa-1e0d-4265-8fbe-5e22df198bee"
}
```

So, I tried to fix this problem by add header to allow origin but it doesn't work.
the following is my coding. my web is hosting on firebase.

```
function RedeemToken(){
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
    myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
    urlencoded.append("client_id", "XXXX");
    urlencoded.append("redirect_uri", "https://XXXX.web.app/LinkToAuthen.html");
    urlencoded.append("client_secret", "XXXX");
    urlencoded.append("code", XXXX);
    urlencoded.append("grant_type", "authorization_code");

    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: urlencoded,
      redirect: 'follow'
    };

    fetch("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```

Comment: Could you please whicg type of application? Angular or react?

Comment: Hi , it's web application with Basic Javascript

Comment: If you are a single page application, I suggest you use the package `@azure/msal-browser` to access token: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-browser

Comment: Also it seems you are using [Client Credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) on a single page application. Its meant for server side/ daemon applications - which is why you get cors issues. You can check [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) which may be better for your case

Comment: Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 11):

Change the App registration -> Authentication->platform type should SPA instead of Web or viceversa.